# Rearranging file contents by shell script

Tags: shell

I have the below text file

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want the file contents to be in the below way

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

How can I go with this?

---

I have the data file below:

```
DATE: 2015-11-30
TIME: 13:15:00
              Charge Remaining (mAh): 4828
              Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5634
```

I want the data arranged in this order-

```
Date,Time,'Charge Remaining','Full Charge Capacity'
```

So, the output should be:

```
2015-11-30,13:15:00,4828,5634
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr '\n' ',' < text-file | sed 's/,$//'
```

Replace all newlines by commas; replace the final comma by 'nothing' (actually, a newline).

Dealing with the more complex data, you want the last field on each line as a field in the CSV-style output.  That's easy with `awk` plus the script from before:

```
awk '{ print $NF }' text-file | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
```

Comment: Jonathan, awesome, Thank you.

Comment: Jonathan, can you also help me here?
DATE: 2015-11-30
TIME: 13:15:00
              Charge Remaining (mAh): 4828
              Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5634

Comment: I can't help you with the battery status because I don't see a question in the comment beyond the 'can you help me here'.

Comment: Jonathan, let me send you a mail to your gmail ID. I 've added the question at the top. Please check this.

Comment: Please note that your 'answer' isn't an answer and should be deleted (please do it, though I've flagged so it will probably be removed soon anyway, but there's less chance of down-votes if you remove it now). I've transferred the material into the question for you — next time, please do that for yourself. And please ask the whole question up front. It is not really fair making people deal with chameleon questions; it is apt to get them antsy. I've addressed your updated question (as I interpreted it) in my updated answer. If my interpretation is wrong, please edit the question to be explicit.

Comment: Jonathan, can you make me understand what does the $NF does?

Comment: Awk automatically splits a line into fields separated by spaces.  The fields are numbered from 1 to `NF` (where `NF` is a variable automatically set by Awk when a line is read), and the fields are referred to as `$1`, `$2`, … but you can use a variable in place of a literal number, so `$NF` is the last field on the line, which is the one with the interesting information in your sample data.  Other tools don't generally make it so easy to pick out the last field (or, if you needed it, the second last field, which is `$(NF-1)` in Awk).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a short shell script to read the data file and output the comma separated values. You can redirect the output to a new file if you choose:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i cnt=0; 
while read -r line; do 
    [ "$cnt" -eq 0 ] && printf "%s" "${line##*: }" || printf ",%s" "${line##*: }"
    ((cnt++))
done < "$1"

printf "\n"
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/charge.txt
DATE: 2015-11-30
TIME: 13:15:00
            Charge Remaining (mAh): 4828
            Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5634
```

**Output**

```
$  bash rfmtcharge.sh dat/charge.txt
2015-11-30,13:15:00,4828,5634
```

If you wanted it in a one-line script, you could use:

```
( declare -i cnt=0; while read -r line; do [ "$cnt" -eq 0 ] && printf "%s" "${line##*: }" || printf ",%s" "${line##*: }"; ((cnt++)); done < dat/charge.txt; printf "\n" )
```

**note:** the one-line script is wrapped in `( ... )` to execute in a subshell.